# What does "It's the support staff" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Daphne is talking on a phone:

> Daphne: We sure do take contributions. We've got high-priced lawyers.

William, who is lawyer for Daphne's team, was mocking joke at Daphne:

> William: High-priced lawyers are working for free. **It's the support
> staff**.

What does "It's the support staff" mean? Does it mean support staff are not
working for free?

Source: The Trial of the Chicago 7 (2020)

Comment: Support staff are the ones who are essential for the system to be up and running. When they are saying "take contributions" that means they are not included in the everyday staff, and even then they have to work for free, which William thinks is an insult to them, hence the mockery. They are working for free.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Does it mean support staff are not working for free?

Comment: The lawyer is making a joke. It's not him they need money for, but Daphne. He says that because Daphne is blaming the lawyers for the runnings costs. So he blames Daphne (mockingly).